# iOS 7 Navigation bar renders incorrect RGB

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiappearance

I'm attempting to make my navigation bar RGB(32,29,29) but when the app launches (currently working in the simulator with Xcode 5.0.2) it is rendered as RGB(42,38,38).

This is the color I want: [image: 32,29,29]

And this is the color I'm getting: [image: 42,38,38]

A subtle difference, but strange. Here's my appearance code in my AppDelegate.m:

```
application.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[UINavigationBar appearance].barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:32.0/255.0 green:29.0/255.0 blue:29.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[UITextField appearance].keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
```

I've tried variations of removing some of those settings to see if perhaps a tint was being applied, but so far I can't figure it out. What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had things render a slightly different color in iOS before and it's frustrating. You can try setting the bar to be not translucent:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

It's worked for me in the past.

Comment: This seems to do the trick. Though, I had to set it on the actual navigationBar: `navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` Your code crashed.

Comment: Ah, glad it worked. I am submitting from my phone and can't test. I'll edit my answer to reflect the correct way.